# CDH4.2.0 Unable to set HBase Compression

Tags: compression, hbase, cloudera

Since we've updated our installation of CDH4.1.2 to CDH4.2.0 we're no longer able to create new tables with enabled compression.
We were using SNAPPY Compression successfully before.
Now when we try to execute a create statement like:

```
create 'tableWithCompression', {NAME => 't1', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY'}
```

an error occurs:

```
ERROR: Compression SNAPPY is not supported. Use one of LZ4 SNAPPY LZO GZ NONE
```

We realized that other compression algorithms weren't found either: e.g. same problem with 'GZ'.

```
ERROR: Compression GZ is not supported. Use one of LZ4 SNAPPY LZO GZ NONE
```

We've added 
"export HBASE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/"
to hbase-env.sh.

Unfortunately this did not fix our problem.

What else can we try?

Comment: Do you get the same problem with NONE as well? I'm guessing this may have something to do with upper case conversion and locales/languages of the environment, since the check that throws this merely looks up an enum defined in the code and not native lib checks.

Comment: Yes, this error also occurs with NONE. Running locale shows "LANG=en_GB.UTF-8".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting the same. This seems to be a bug in the admin.rb script.

The code in question is this:

```
      if arg.include?(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor::COMPRESSION)
        compression = arg[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor::COMPRESSION].upcase
        unless org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.Compression::Algorithm.constants.include?(compression)      
          raise(ArgumentError, "Compression #{compression} is not supported. Use one of " + org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.Compression::Algorithm.constants.join(" ")) 
        else 
          family.setCompressionType(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.Compression::Algorithm.valueOf(compression))
        end
      end
```

Some "p" statements later, I know that. compression is `"SNAPPY"`, and `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.Compression::Algorithm.constants` is `[:LZ4, :SNAPPY, :LZO, :GZ, :NONE]`.

See the diffrence? We're comparing strings and symbols. The quick fix is to change the line that sets compression to the following:

```
    compression = arg[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor::COMPRESSION].upcase.to_sym
```

I guess this has to do with there being a ton of different jruby variants and configurations. I suppose in some, the constants are strings, in others symbols. A more permanent fix is to use `to_sym` on both ends of the comparison.

Comment: Sorry, my internet connection here is very crappy. I can't git clone hbase, and therefore cannot submit a patch :(.